# How do I stabilize a lecithin-based foam?

Tags: molecular-gastronomy

I've made quite a few foams using the standard technique of adding powdered lecithin to my flavor base, and then agitating with an immersion blender in a wide, shallow container, with the blender near the surface so it beats in lots of air. This works ok, but I find the foams don't hold as long as I would like, often just a minute or two. Is there anything I can do to make them more stable for service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd look into:

- contaminants
- the container you use
- lecithin ratio
- (air) moisture
- inert gas use (which implies a different technique.

[This link on foams](http://www.edinformatics.com/math_science/science_of_cooking/foams1.htm) to the [food science pages at edinformatic](http://www.edinformatics.com/math_science/science_of_cooking/)s looks good. Perhaps it can help you out further.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the best foams with lecithin come from two major factors. One is the temp. is should be around 35-45C. the second is to be sure to have some oil or fat content so that the liquid has some thing to emulsify with, which will help stabilize the foam.